# Get helper not working for attrs hash

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

```
{{my-component can-delete=true canDelete=true}}
```

In the `my-component` template I want to access `can-delete` from the `attrs` object.

```
{{attrs.can-delete}} <!-- does not work, prints blank, should print true -->
{{attrs.canDelete}} <!-- works, prints true-->
```

I tried using the get helper

```
{{get attrs 'can-delete'}}
```

but get an error `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The first argument to {{get}} must be a stream`

How can I access object properties from HTMLBars that are not in the usual format?

Comment: You dont need to use "attrs". Just go {{can-delete}}

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ember-twiddle that seems to be working fine even without the 'get' helper: http://ember-twiddle.com/f101eb114ea0b8ad3e92